# How to re-render JS-generated content after an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I'm creating a website that has an audio player. The idea is that the music doesn't stop while you're navigating the site, so I implemented a type of deep linking with jQuery and the `load()` method, which works fine.

The problem is that if I enter directly to [this url](http://radio.miladonintendo.cl/super-nintendo/super-mario-world/fortress-theme/), the social buttons load correctly, but if I access it through a link within the website, the social buttons don't load. You can see this issue [here](http://radio.miladonintendo.cl/super-nintendo/super-mario-world/) and then entering the "Fortress Theme" post.

Is there any way to re-render those buttons and, in general, any type of content like this (like AdSense ads) after the AJAX call? I tried with `FB.XFBML.parse();` for the Facebook button, but it didn't work.

Here is the code that loads the pages via AJAX:

```
$("body").on('click', 'a:not(.social-tooltip, .fancy, #play, #stop, #back-to-top)', function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr('href').split("#");
    if(!link_is_external(this) && url[1] == undefined) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(url[1] != "comments") {
            var href = $(this).attr('href'),
            title = $(this).text();
            loadContent(href,title);
            history.pushState({path: href, titel: title}, $(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('href'));
        }
    }
});

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    loadContent(e.state.path, e.state.titel);
}, false);

function loadContent(href,title){
    var href = href,
        container = $('section.content');

    container.load( href +' section.content', function(){
        // container.fadeIn(200);
        $('title').replaceWith('<title>' + title + '</title>');
        $("#back-to-top").trigger("click");
    });         
};
```

If you need more information, just tell me and I will edit this question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: would be better if you post code.

Comment: I added the code that loads the pages with AJAX. Thank you!

Comment: FB.XFBML.parse() is the only (and correct) way. you just need to call it when the elements are in the DOM already.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. Anyway, that should work with the Facebook button, but what about Twitter and Google+ buttons and all other kind of dynamic content? Is it really impossible to re-load them?